# Why in the infinite loop the sliders in swiper js jump when the loop ends

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I have to design a slider exactly like this. Like this [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/developers) or this [piotnetgrid.com](https://piotnetgrid.com/demos/).

I could not solve the following issue with swiper:
I want to use the loop in this slider.
In this slider, I have put 20 photo slides. When autoplay reaches image 19 and 20 and enters the loop to restart, this is done by jumping.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".masonrySwiper", {
    direction:"horizontal",
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 8,
    simulateTouch:false,

    autoplay: {
      enabled: true,
      delay: 1,          
      pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    centerInsufficientSlides:true,
    speed: 700,               
});
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper{
   box-sizing: border-box !important;
   display: flex !important;
   flex-flow: column wrap !important;
   height: 80vh !important;
   text-align: center !important;
   text-transform: uppercase !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   left: 0;
   transition-timing-function: linear !important;
} 

.grids {
    align-items: center !important;
    background: white !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    color: white !important;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-grow: 0 !important;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
  
.grids:nth-child(6n-5) {
    height: 30% !important;
    width: 25% !important;
}

.grids:nth-child(6n-4) {
    height: 70% !important;
    width: 25% !important;
}

.grids:nth-child(6n-3) {
    height: 50% !important;
    width: 30% !important;
}

.grids:nth-child(6n-2) {
    height: 50% !important;
    width: 30% !important;
}
  
.grids:nth-child(6n-1) {
    height: 60% !important;
    width: 40% !important;
}

.grids:nth-child(6n) {
    height:40% !important;
    width: 40% !important;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="swiper masonrySwiper" style="border: 3px solid red; width: 100%;">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="border: 3px solid green; width: 100%;">
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/1') !important">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/2') !important">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/3') !important">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/4') !important">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/5') !important">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/6') !important">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/7') !important">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/8') !important">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/9') !important">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/10') !important">Slide 10</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/11') !important">Slide 11</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/12') !important">Slide 12</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/13') !important">Slide 13</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/14') !important">Slide 14</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/15') !important">Slide 15</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/16') !important">Slide 16</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/17') !important">Slide 17</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/18') !important">Slide 18</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/19') !important">Slide 19</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide grids" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/20') !important">Slide 20</div>
      
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I also had a similar issue, in version 9 amount of slides in loop mode should be at least 2x of slidesPerView value. Thought this may help anyone having the same issue.
[See Documentatoion](https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide-v9#loop-mode)

> Loop mode has been fully reworked in version 9 and now instead of duplicating slides, it rearrange current ones dynamically.
>
> It comes with new limitation. Amount of slides in loop mode should be at least 2x of **slidesPerView** value.
>
> **loopedSlides** with new logic works in a bit different way, and you probably should remove it or make sure it is less or equal to **slidesPerView**.

Example:

```
const slides = [
    <img src='/image1' key={1}/>,
    <img src='/image2' key={2}/>,
    <img src='/image3' key={3}/>,
    <img src='/image4' key={4}/>,
    <img src='/image5' key={5}/>,
    <img src='/image6' key={6}/>,
]
return (
    <Swiper
        effect='slide'
        slidesPerView={3} 
        //since the slides array length is 6,
        //slidesPerView should be less than or equal to 3
        loop={true}
        autoplay={{
            "delay": 1,
            "disableOnInteraction": false,
            "pauseOnMouseEnter": false,
            "stopOnLastSlide": false,
            "waitForTransition": true
        }}
        modules={[Autoplay]}
    >
    {slides.map((item) => <SwiperSlide>{item}</SwiperSlide>)}
    </Swiper>
)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue using V8, that's definitely a bad move from the devs for the case if numOfSlides < (2 * slidesPerView), there should be an option to keep the logic as it was before : duplicating slides.
https://codepen.io/XavC/pen/BaGxJQV

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the latest version of swiper.js.
All the working solutions i’ve found on the internet using a older version of swiper.js. So maybe its a bug in a newer version of swiper, because there were already similar bugs in older versions. https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues?q=loop+jump

Comment: Please try to add loopedSlides property. Maybe it will help you

Comment: @ShulykVolodymyr thanks for the hint, i already tried this solution (since i found it on the internet), but still not working.

Comment: Downgrading to latest v8 fixed all my Swiper.js problems.

Answer (score 1):

The jump occurs, when swiper js is in a loop mode. It creates duplicate slides after the last and the first slide, if you want to go backwards. I will give you an example:

```js
swiper.on('transitionEnd', function () {
    let activeSlide = swiper.realIndex +1; // Index of Current active slide
    let previousSlide = swiper.previousIndex -2; // Index of previous active slide
    if (previousSlide == -1) { 
        previousSlide = 0;
    } else if (previousSlide == 
        document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide').length) { 
        // When swiper loops, slideChange 
        // gets fired twice and messes up animations. This 
        // prevents it from doing so.
      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, I was able to fix it with `loopedSlides` property. When I say how many slides is in the loop it started to work without a jump.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of swiper? I couldn’t get it work with the loopedSlides property either.

Comment: My bad. I had a similar issue, but not the same. Experienced jump without loop: true, when manually switching slides, maybe that's why it's not working for your case. Answering your question, which is not relevant anymore, I guess - the latest swiperjs at the moment 8.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

**This Combination Worked with me :**

```
slideToClickedSlide: true,
loop: true,
loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
autoplay: {
  delay: 6000,
  disableOnInteraction: false,
  reverseDirection: true,
}
```

add it to swiper configuration

Answer (score 0):

Works if  `centeredSlides: true` )))
Bugs of Swiper )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution for Swiper 11**

I see a lot of comments that suggest to downgrade, but I think in the new version they just simply renamed it to `loopAdditionalSlides` I tried that one in stead of `loopedSlides` and I got it working again using **Swiper 11.0.3**